# How to change attribute to a whole class of elements using jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change a attribute to lots of elements witch all have the same class.

I have lots of "a" tags with a "data-lc-categories= all" attribute.

I want to change that attribute(data-lc-categories) to all the a tags with a class of animation to data-lc-categories = "animation".

My problem is that if I try to select the elements using a id it works using the:

```
setAttribute('data-lc-categories', 'animation'); // javascript
```

OR

```
$('#test1').attr({
    "data-lc-categories": "animation",
    "title": "some title"
}); // jQuery
```

but when I try with

```
document.getElementsByClassName(".img_portfolio_animation")
 .setAttribute('data-lc-categories', 'animation');
```

OR

```
$('.animation').attr("data-lc-categories": "animation")
```

it doesn't work.

```
<div class="new_filter_btns_container">
    <ul>
         <li id="filter_All" class="filter_btn">All</li>
         <li id="filter_animations" class="filter_btn">Animations</li>
         <li id="filter_interior" class="filter_btn">Interior Renders</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<a id="test1" class="animation all" href="" data-rel="lightcase:myCollection" data-lc-categories="All">Animation</a>
<a class="animation all" href="" data-rel="lightcase:myCollection" data-lc-categories="All">Animation</a>
<a class="animation all" href="" data-rel="lightcase:myCollection" data-lc-categories="All">Animation</a>
<a class="animation all" href="" data-rel="lightcase:myCollection" data-lc-categories="All">Animation</a>
<a class="interior all" href="" data-rel="lightcase:myCollection" data-lc-categories="All">Interior</a>
<a class="interior all" href="" data-rel="lightcase:myCollection" data-lc-categories="All">Interior</a>
<a class="interior all"     href="" data-rel="lightcase:myCollection" data-lc-categories="All">Interior</a>
<a class="interior all" href="" data-rel="lightcase:myCollection" data-lc-categories="All">Interior</a>
```

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plain JS version doesn't work because `getElementsByClassName()` returns a nodeList. As such you cannot call `setAttribute()` on it. You need to loop through the elements individually and call the method on them one by one, something like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(".img_portfolio_animation");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].setAttribute('data-lc-categories', 'animation');
}
```

The jQuery version doesn't work simply because you need to separate arguments with a comma, not a colon:

```
$('.animation').attr("data-lc-categories", "animation")
```